# Param I'm trying to pass through hidden field is showing as an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am trying to use a hidden field in a form to pass a param with a value of 1 to a method in my controller, which will add the value to the quantity of an order item in a shopping cart. When I check what I'm getting with a binding pry, I see that for `params` the :update_by param I am trying to pass is showing as an object `"order_items=>{"update_by"=>"1"}`. So, when I try to grab the param in the method using `params[:update_by]`, I get nil (or 0 if `.to_i`). Why is the param an object?

Please see the html for the form

```
<% if @order_items.any? %>
  <% @order_items.each do |item| %>
    <%= form_for item do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :update_by, value: 1 %>
        <%= button_tag type:"submit", class: "cart_quantity_button" 
        do %>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the method in the controller

```
def update
  @order = current_order
  @item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
  @item.update(:quantity=> @item.quantity + params[:update_by].to_i)
  @item.save!
  redirect_to cart_path
end

private

def item_params
  params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, 
  :user_id, :update_by)
  end
end
```

I am grabbing the data I want from the other varaiables in my method. The problem is that I can't grab the value of :update_by if it's an object, right? Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this for your form:

```
<%= form_for item do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :update_by, value: 1 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and `item` is an `OrderItem`. That means that everything that `f`'s methods produce (such as that `f.hidden_field`) will live inside the `order_item` namespace. Hence the

```
"order_item"=>{"update_by"=>"1"}
```

in your controller. You can also see this in your `item_params` controller method:

```
def item_params
  params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id, :update_by)
  end
end
```

The `require` call means that you're looking for `"order_item"` and the `permit` call means that you're looking for those things *inside* `"order_item"`.

You should use your `item_params` method to unpack the parameters:

```
@item.update(:quantity => @item.quantity + item_params[:update_by].to_i)
```

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense. I forgot to add that we did remove `:update_by` from `item_params` and updated the quantity in the method using `@item.update(:quantity => params[:button])` instead. In case anyone was confused about that.

Answer (score 0):

My friend found a solution for me by moving the value of the param to the button instead of a hidden form field.

```
  <%= form_for (item) do |f| %>
    <% button_tag type:"submit", :value => item.quantity.to_i + 1, class: "cart_quantity_button" do %>
      <p><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for (item) do |f| %>
    <% button_tag type:"submit", :value => item.quantity.to_i - 1, class: "cart_quantity_button" do %>
      <p><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

If you have an explanation for this solution, please let me know. We are both noobs. Thanks!